# UWP: Why is this Execution Alias not working? The App gets stuck on splash screen

Tags: uwp

I am trying to use a Execution Alias for an UWP App, but when I run it 
[image: Command line]

The App gets stuck on this screen:

[image: UWP splash screen]

on the Package.appxmanifest file I have:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="UWPApp4.App"
      >
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="UWPApp4"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="UWPApp4"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>

      <Extensions>
        <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias">
          <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
            <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp1234.exe" />
          </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
        </uap5:Extension>
      </Extensions>

    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

Project in a ZIP file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YKp2SevzkoPWulN2VrueYe17H7DF1sdy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle OnActivated in your App.xaml.cs to handle the incoming arguments and create and navigate to your main window. You can reuse or refactor much of the code from your existing OnLaunched method to create a new root Frame if needed and navigate it to your MainPage.

The IActivatedEventArgs.Kind will be [ActivationKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind).CommandLineLaunch and the IActivatedEventArgs will be a [CommandLineActivatedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.commandlineactivatedeventargs)

See [Command-Line Activation of Universal Windows Apps](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps) for more info.

To debug this open your project properties, go to the debug tab, and check the Start action: Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts. Set a breakpoint on your OnActivated method, launch the app from the command line, and it should break in your OnActivated method

Comment: With the information that you provider it worked on a Command Prompt . I tried to call MyApp1234.exe from Ubuntu WSL Bash, it does not give error, but also does not start the App. I tested calc.exe then the UWP Calc starts.

Comment: Just for testing, I tried to upload this same App, unchanged to Raspberry Pi, this error appears in Visual Studio 2017: Error  DEP8000 : Unexpected deployment failure : RemoteCommandException : AppxManifest.xml(34,14): error 0x80070005: Cannot register the 026a7151-df43-42c1-aed7-662903f9ee7d_1.0.0.0_arm__4swv3pr9mz72j package because the following error was encountered while registering the windows.appExecutionAlias extension: Access is denied.
.  Try again and contact the package publisher if the problem persists.
0x80070005

Comment: Yes, also I had to remove Executable & EntryPoint in uap5:Extension